# How to avoid observable delay in angular or make sure my function gets called only when observable is ready

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, observable, angularfire

I have a login function which calls Firebase SDK method to authenticate with email. This Firebase method returns non-null Promise of `UserCredential`, so it says in Firebase docs. So I use `.then()` to wait until user is logged in, authenticated and then console.log his info and redirect to home. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I get undefined from `console.log(value.email);` in the console, `not working` from

```
if (this.userDetails) {
console.log("hello im user" + " " + email);
} else {
console.log("not working");
}
```

and `errorTypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined` from:

```
.catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log("error" + error);
    });
```

then immediately after one or two seconds, it finally starts working, prints out `hello im user lajmis@mail.com` from

```
constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;
    this.loggedIn = !!sessionStorage.getItem('user');

    this.user.subscribe(
        (user) => {
          if (user && user.uid) {
            this.userDetails = user;
            var email = this.userDetails.email;
            console.log("hello im user" + " " + email);
            this.setCurrentUser(email);
            this.loggedIn = true;
            console.log(this.userDetails);

          } else {
            this.userDetails = null;
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

and `this.userDetails`.

Why is this happening? Here is the full code:

```
export class AuthService {
  private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  private userDetails: firebase.User = null;
  public loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;
    this.loggedIn = !!sessionStorage.getItem('user');

    this.user.subscribe(
        (user) => {
          if (user && user.uid) {
            this.userDetails = user;
            var email = this.userDetails.email;
            console.log("hello im user" + " " + email);
            this.setCurrentUser(email);
            this.loggedIn = true;
            console.log(this.userDetails);

          } else {
            this.userDetails = null;
          }
        }
      );
  }

  // Set current user in your session after a successful login
    setCurrentUser(email: string): void {
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', email);
        this.loggedIn = true;
    }

    // Get currently logged in user from session
    getCurrentUser(): string | any {
        return sessionStorage.getItem('user') || undefined;
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
    }

  logUserIn(email, pass) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(function(value) {

        console.log(value.email);
        this.router.navigate(['']);

    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log("error" + error);
    });
if (this.userDetails) {
console.log("hello im user" + " " + email);
} else {
console.log("not working");
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `logUserIn` from?

Comment: @sketchthat in login.component.ts I have a function `login() {
          this.auth.logUserIn(this.form.value.email, this.form.value.password);
};` and I call `login()` in my form by binding it to `ngSubmit`

Answer (score 1):

`logUserIn` is non blocking - so the workflow will be;

- call `constructor`
- call `this.user.subscribe`
- call `logUserIn`
- call `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword`
- call `if (this.userDetails)`
- receive response from `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword`
- call `.then(function(value) {`
- call `this.router.navigate(['']);`
- receive response from `this.user.subscribe`

Therefore the `console.log` will output `not working` and a few seconds later the `this.user.subscribe` receives the `user` object.

`router` cannot be accessed because you're not using an `arrow function`. Use an `arrow function` to maintain access to `this`.

Perhaps try a workflow such as the following;

```js
constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
  this.user = _firebaseAuth.authState;
  this.loggedIn = !!sessionStorage.getItem('user');

  this.user
    .subscribe(user => {
      console.log('constructor user: ' + user);
      this.updateUser(user);
    });
}

updateUser(user) {
  if (user && user.id) {
    this.userDetails = user;
    var email = this.userDetails.email;
    console.log("hello im user" + " " + email);
    this.setCurrentUser(email);
    this.loggedIn = true;
    console.log(this.userDetails);
  } else {
    this.userDetails = null;
  }
}

logUserIn(email, pass) {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
    .then(user => {
      console.log('logUserIn: ' + user);

      this.updateUser(user);

      this.router.navigate(['']);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log("error" + error);
    });
}
```

This way both the `logUserIn` and `constructor` can update the `userDetails` when they receive the user object from Firebase.

It will also avoid you redirecting before `this.userDetails` have been set.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get `not working` to console which means it skips `.then()` in `logUserIn()` and `errorReferenceError: user is not defined` from `.catch()`

Comment: I just realised I had `then(value` and it should have been `then(user`.

Comment: You will continue to get `not working` as described above. Because the `then` is non blocking. You need to use `await/async` if you want to change the behaviour.